# Display String From Array Randomly, only once, and change each day

Tags: iphone, string, random, plist

I am working on a quote app, and I have my plist setup and each string in the plist stands as its own quote.  What are some ways that I can have a TextView in one of my Views display a quote, and change it at midnight each day, and then mark the string as used, so that it will not repeat it, and keep going through at random order?

Comment: Why not just show them in order... Since you will show each string only once the order they occur in the plist is as random as any other order!

Comment: There is one different @idz in that if its random at runtime two users with separate phones would see different quotes on the same day. However if its ordered, even randomly, each user would see the same quote each day. Or atleast in the same order if it was in a way that they had to actually look at the quote before it was used.

Comment: @RyanPoolos Yes, provided they both start using the app on the same day. Was merely making the point the once you add a condition (like not repeating) is not really as random as you might think! In addition to the comment I did also explain provide an answer suggest to the OP how to do what they want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your plist to either remove the quote or set a flag as used then exclude those from being selected.

As far as when to mark one as used. I'm not sure everyday at midnight works with your model If its truly random then marking them as used at midnight doesn't make much sense since they may not open the app every day and would miss random quotes. Where as if it were ordered there would be a quote a day.

EDIT FROM OP:
In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunch I added this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {

    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];

    [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"verseKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
NSTimeInterval date = [defaults doubleForKey:@"startTimeInterval"];

NSTimeInterval dateNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

NSTimeInterval difference = dateNow - date;

difference = difference / 84000;

if(difference >= 0 && difference <= 1) {

}   

if(difference >= 1 ) {
    NSLog(@"ITSMORE");
    NSInteger savedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"verseKey"];
    savedIndex +=1;
    if (savedIndex == 200) {
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"verseKey"];
        dateNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        [defaults setDouble:dateNow forKey:@"startTimeInterval"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    else {
    [defaults setInteger:savedIndex forKey:@"verseKey"];
    dateNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    [defaults setDouble:dateNow forKey:@"startTimeInterval"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

I believe that this code should set the value of 0 for verseKey on firstRun and synchronize it with NSUserDefaults.  Then, each time it is launched, it will see if more than 24 hours have passed.  If it has, then it will add 1 to the key of verseKey until it hits 200 (I have a total of 200 quotes).  Once 200 has been hit, it will reset it to 0.  Then I set the TextView to objectAtIndex:key for verses, so that it will change.  Sound about right?

Comment: The problem with flagging used quotes is that, say you have large number of quotes, as you use them up the you random index will keep hitting used ones and you will have to iterate. (In the worst case if you had a really large number of quotes and only a few left to choose some you could be waiting quite some time to land on an unused one ;-) ). It's a lot better to keep a set of unused indices; then you can always pick one randomly in a single iteration. If you actually remove the quotes you will need to still keep the original list around otherwise you will run out!

Comment: I have just 200 quotes right now, and you bring up a good point about them missing quotes if they don't open each day.  The quotes are in an order right now with several in a row from each book, and I'd prefer them to be random, so its not a week of looking at the app and only seeing one particular style of quote.  I may try and randomize the order of the array on my own before loading into xcode, and then have it progress in order, but I'm still not sure how to say, when the app is opened, display row 0, then wait 24 hours and display row 1...

Comment: If you want it to be 24 hours from when they last opened the app thats extremely easy Just store an `NSDate` then check it on launch using `timeIntervalSinceDate:` However if you want it to be a daily thing regardless of what time of day they look then you'll need to do more complicated checking.

Comment: Just had a thought...if I am doing this so it would only change it once every 24 hours with checking time, wouldn't it keep it from changing if the user opened it once every 23 hours?

Comment: No. it would basically me if the time since last open >24 new code reset time. Otherwise do nothing. So if they open it 100 times or 1 time in that 24 hour period they wouldn't get a code until 24 hours was up. On the flip side if they opened it once a week depending on how you handled for it they would get a code a week unless you made it skip codes based on how many hours over 24 they were.

Comment: Edited to show that I set a nsuserdefault for integer and start with 0.  Each time get new code, it adds 1.  Then I have the objectAtIndex be that NSUserDefault, so that way it will increase to next string if they open after 25 hours, or if they open a week later.  Open once a day will get 200 quotes in 200 days, open once a week will take over 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Update: My previous answer mentioned `NSMutableSet` thinking about `NSMutableArray` is probably a better match for you requirements.

Keep an array of the indices of the *unused* strings (you will need to store this persistently, for example in `NSUserDefaults`). You can just initialize this in a loop filling it with the indices of all your quotes. So if you had 200 this array would have 200 elements [0..199]. Each day, or whenever is appropriate, choose a random index from this array, use this as the index of that day's quote. Remove it from the array and write the modified array back to your `NSUserDefaults`. When the array has zero elements repopulate with all indices. Check out `NSUserDefaults`, `NSMutableArray` and `arc4random`.

For example, let's say you had 5 quotes.

```
Day 1:
  unusedQuotes = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
  randomly choose index 2.
  unusedQuotes[2] is 2 so show quote[2] and remove unusedQuotes[2] from array

Day 2:
  unusedQuotes = [ 0, 1, 3, 4 ];
  randomly choose index 3.
  unusedQuotes[3] is 4 so show quote[4] and remove unusedQuotes[4] from array

Day 3:
  unusedQuotes = [ 0, 1, 3];
  ...
  and so on
```

You should also save the date on which you choose a quote. When the user uses your app again if it is the same date do not choose a new quote. Only choose a new quote if they day is different. This way you will no miss quotes or show more than one quote on a give day.